# Is it possible to color kmeans results according to its annotation, rather than by the clustering results?

Tags: r, annotations, cluster-analysis

I have labeled data and I'd like to estimate whether clustering results agree with these labels.
In hierarchical clustering, I was able to do so using:

```
pheatmap(data,annotation_col=metadata,annotation_row=metadata,annotation_colors=anno_colors)
```

Is it possible to do so also with `kmeans` results? I tried `fviz_cluster` but I could not find how to color each point according to its annotation and not by its cluster.

Comment: you just use a different vector for color instead of cluster: `km <- kmeans(iris[, 1:2], 2); plot(iris[, 1:2], col = km$cluster); plot(iris[, 1:2], col = iris$Species)`

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. However, to my best understanding it works only when clustering is based on only two features, in your example: iris[,1:2]. Is it possible to color each point according to annotation also when more features are used for clustering (e.g. km <- kmeans(iris[,1:4),2)? I known that fviz_cluster can show the points on a 2-D principal component  plane (e.g. PC1 vs. PC2). However, I could not find a way to ask fviz_cluster to color the points according to their annotations?

Comment: `pc <- prcomp(iris[, 1:4])$x[, 1:2]; plot(pc); km <- kmeans(pc, 2); plot(pc, col = km$cluster); plot(pc, col = iris$Species)`

Comment: Thanks rawr. You answer my question perfectly.
One issue is that we now have to look at two figures: in one the points are colored according to their clusters and in the other according to their annotation.
A nice feature of fviz_cluster is that it can draw an ellipse around each cluster.
Therefore, if the points can be colored according to their annotation in fvis_cluster, all the information can be displayed in one figure. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find how to compare known labels with kmeans clustering results in one figure using fviz_cluster.
Instead I colored the dots according to their labels, and shape the dots according to their clusters.

```
    iris.scaled <- scale(iris[, 1:4])
    pc <- prcomp(iris.scaled)
    km <- kmeans(iris.scaled, 3, nstart = 100)
    pca.var <- pc$sdev^2
    pca.var.per <- round(pca.var/sum(pca.var)*100, 1)
    # Color according to iris$Species
    typeSp<-as.vector(iris$Species)
    colvec<-typeSp
    colvec[is.element(typeSp,"setosa")] = "red"
    colvec[is.element(typeSp,"versicolor")] = "blue"
    colvec[is.element(typeSp,"virginica")] = "magenta"
    # Shape according to kmeans cluster
    typeCl<-km$cluster
    pchvec<-1:length(colvec)
    pchvec[is.element(typeCl,1)] = 0
    pchvec[is.element(typeCl,2)] = 19 
    pchvec[is.element(typeCl,3)] = 17
    plot(pc$x[,1], pc$x[,2], col=colvec, pch=pchvec, 
         xlab = paste("PC1 (",pca.var.per[1],"%)"),  
         ylab = paste("PC2 (",pca.var.per[2],"%)"), 
         main="Compare known label (colors) to Kmeans cluster (shapes)")
    legend("topright",legend=c("setosa","versicolor","virginica"),
           col=c("blue","red","magenta"),
           cex=0.9, pch=c(8,8,8))
```